# rewriterule and view the path of the pictures

Tags: .htaccess

I have a file located at:

> /galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/phoca_thumb_l_image001.jpg

I want to be able to view it by navigating to the following path on my website:

> /galeria/a1/phoca_thumb_l_image001.jpg

Currently I have the following rules in my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/([^-]*)$ galeria/a1/$1/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ index.php?page=$1&album=$2&lang=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)/([^-]*)$ index.php?page=$1&lang=$2 [L]
```

What do I need to change to make it work?

Comment: Nothing to do with php.

Comment: I corrected the theme and tags.

Comment: So everything in `galeria/a1/` should serve `galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/` is that right?

Comment: yeah, but on this time, i'm just trying to view although one picture.

full path is like http://localhost/galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/phoca_thumb_l_image001.jpg , I'd like to show on:
http://localhost/galeria/a1/phoca_thumb_l_image001.jpg

Comment: Yea so your rule is backwards. You are writing `galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/([^-]*)$` to `galeria/a1/$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^galeria/a1/([^-]*)$ galeria/a1_files/vlb_images1/$1 [L,NC]
```